# Databricks structured streaming with Snowflake as source?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

Is it possible to use a Snowflake table as a source for spark structured streaming in Databricks? When I run the following pyspark code:

```
    options = dict(sfUrl=our_snowflake_url,
              sfUser=user,
              sfPassword=password,
              sfDatabase=database,
              sfSchema=schema,
              sfWarehouse=warehouse)

    df = spark.readStream.format("snowflake") \
              .schema(final_struct) \
              .options(**options) \
              .option("dbtable", "BASIC_DATA_TEST") \
              .load()
```

I get this warning:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source snowflake does not support streamed reading

I haven't been able to find anything in the Spark Structured Streaming Docs that explicitly says Snowflake is supported as a source, but I'd like to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: How is snowflake going to stream data out? What would be the trigger to push a piece of data out?

Comment: OK so looks like you can effectively enable CDC in snowflake https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html then you'd need an external process to check for changed data and stream it out. Which is a very convoluted way to implement streaming. I suspect it would make more sense to utilise whatever is loading the data and stream from that.

Answer (score 2):

The Spark Snowflake connector currently does not support using the .writeStream/.readStream calls from Spark Structured Streaming